# Extracting first item in each row in [r]

Tags: extract

I have a column with multiple items, separated by semicolons, in each row but i would like only the first item in each row. My data looks like this:

```
1   mmSM7.3.54;IGHV14-3*01;musIGHV236
2   mm7183.20.37;IGHV5-17*01;musIGHV219
3   mmIGHV5-9-1*02;musIGHV207;7183.14.25
4   mm7183.20.37;IGHV5-17*01;musIGHV219
5   mmIGHV7-1*03;S107.1.42
6   mmIGHV9-2*01;VH9.13;musIGHV242;VGAM3.8-2-59
7   mmmusIGHV231;SM7.2.49;IGHV14-2*01
```

I would like a column that has just the first item of each row that looks like this:

```
1   mmSM7.3.54
2   mm7183.20.37
3   mmIGHV5-9-1*02
4   mm7183.20.37
5   mmIGHV7-1*03
6   mmIGHV9-2*01
7   mmmusIGHV231
```

Does anyone know a way to do this? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the first item in each record up to the first semicolon ; ?  You did not mention file type, but if it is text, csv, rtf or xlsx, you can do this quickly and easily in Excel or most other spreadsheet applications.
1) Launch Excel, use File > Open (change file type to All Files *.*) and open your file
2) Select the column or all the cells that contain your data
3)Click the DATA tab and choose Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > check the Semicolon box > Finish
4) The first item in each record will now be in its own column. You can copy this column and save it in a new file or just delete all the stuff you don't want and save the original file in the same file format as before.

Comment: Yes I do mean the first item up to the semicolon. It is a text file but it is only a portion of the hundreds of thousands of lines in the file so I would like to use r if possible. Thanks for your help